# I cant open a dir using php opendir

Tags: php, opendir

I have code as below:

```
$dir = opendir("D:/Marcin");
if ($dir) {
echo "OK";
}
else {
echo "not ok";
}
```

and I get not ok, why??

Comment: It should generate a warning telling you why if it returned FALSE.

Comment: Have you enabled `error_reporting`? What does it say? (Yes, enable it.)

Comment: it says "[28-Nov-2012 17:31:56] PHP Warning:  opendir(D:/Marcin) [<a href='function.opendir'>function.opendir</a>]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home4/imaptwof/public_html/ager.php on line 10"

Comment: yeah thats why it wouldn`t probably open.. but if you run it in a local server that can open :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to open a directory server-side. If you were doing so locally, it would work - as I can see that you are getting the directory from your PC, but instead, you are attempting to execute the script in the client-side, and getting a server-side result.

This means that if that directory doesn't exist on your server, the server will not be able to find the file - and will return false.

At a certain point, you must check whether the directory exists on your server.

```
localserver === local directory = true;
webserver === web directory = true;
```

If both of the two are cross-referenced, it will return to false.

```
$dir = opendir("D:/Marcin"); // Check whether the directory exists on your server.
if ($dir) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Not OK";
}
```

Hope this assists.